# Two lists have at least one common element without Prolog built-in predicates

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog-for-sharing

I am new to prolog.I want to write compare_lists/2 which will compare 2 lists and return true if they have at least one common element. I know this can be done with something like that

```
common_list([H|_],T) :- member(H,T).
common_list([_|T],L) :- common_list(T,L).

common_list2(L1,L2) :- member(X,L1),member(X,L2).
```

but I want to do it without  Prolog built-in predicates. I tried writing this

```
common_elements([H|_],[H|_]).
common_elements(L,[_|T]) :- common_elements(L,T).
common_elements([_|T],L):-common_elements(T,L).
```

but when I ask the online swish prolog tool `common_elements([3,13,8,1],[5,3,7,3,1]).` It answers true 37 times not 3 like the common_list/2 and common_list2/2 (I have to use cut to get only 1 instead of 3 but that's a different story).

Answer (score 1):

You can write the member function very easily yourself

```
my_member(H, [H|_]).
my_member(X, [_|T]) :-
    my_member(X,T).
```

Comment: Your first clause is unnecessary, since if you omit it, Prolog will already fail.

Comment: You're right! Thanks for your comment. I've corrected the code ...

Answer (score 1):

According to your condition when two Lists have at least one element in common return `True` and `False` if they no elements in common.

All you have to do is check if `Head` of your list exists in your second List. If `Head` is present in second List return True. Else repeat the process for rest of the process for the tail of the first list.

My approach is given below:-

```
is_member(X,[X|_]):- !.
is_member(X,[_|T]):- is_member(X,T).

compare1([],[]):- false.
compare1([H|_],List):- is_member(H,List) , !.
compare1([H|T],List):- \+is_member(H,List) , compare1(T,List).
```

**OUTPUT**

```
?- compare1([3,4],[1,2,2]).
   false
?- compare1([1,2,3,4],[5,6]).
   false
?- compare1([1,2,3],[4,5,6,3]).
   true
?- compare1([1,2,3],[]).
   false
?- compare1([],[]).
   false
?- compare1([],[1,2,3]).
   false
```

Hope this helped you.